# How to decide the quality of a distance measure in machine learning techniques?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

How can I decide if a given distance metric is a good?

Comment: Is this the whole question? Is a good what?

Comment: Also, please give us some context. What exactly is the problem you're trying to tackle using machine learning?

Answer (score 1):

Classification or clustering?

For classification, use whichever gives the highest cross-validated accuracy (or whichever quality measure you need).

For clustering, you need to pick a criteria for cluster quality, and choose the one that gives you the best cluster quality:

http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2284239?uid=3739448&uid=2&uid=3737720&uid=4&sid=21101924573361 (jstor, not free)

Answer (score 0):

The metric is good, if it **works for your problem**.

In classification, it's as simple as that. If it gives good results, go with it. Otherwise, try a different metric.