# Metric validity in Nearest Neighbors

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Does kNN algorithm require that the distance follows distance axioms? What happened if I apply a metric which fails:

```
d(a,c) < d(a,b) + d(b,c)
```

Same question for KMeans clustering?

Comment: see my edit, it was a bit late when i answered yesterday, and it didnt cover everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kNN only requires a proximity measure where the smaller value means closer. That is because kNN compares the new observation with the training examples and finds the k closest ones (the first k with the lowest proximity value).
For kMeans [use search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509516/is-triangle-inequality-necessary-for-kmeans).

**EDIT:**
Even though kNN doesnt need the triangle equation, it runs in O(n*m) time, where n is the size of the training set and m is the size of the evaluated set. Optimizations usually require at least the triangle equation to stand, although some of them have more constraints (eg: k-d trees only work in euclidean space). See [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/5/nearest-neighbor-data-structure-for-non-euclidean-configuration-space) for more info.